# AWS crawler table locations

Tags: aws-glue

I'm currently learning aws glue, and the first part seems to be to use the crawler to find the table schemas.

I have a couple of buckets in S3. One is called dgt-raw. It has a file which is a csv with the path dgt-raw/accounts/account1/account1-data.csv

I have a crawler, that has an include path s3://dgt-raw/.

It finds the file ok, but does not pick up the name properly, it calls it the same name as the bucket, and also does not get the location correct?

Name    dgt_raw
Description 
Database    dgt-metadata-db
Classification  csv
Location    s3://dgt-raw/

I would have expected it to give the name "account1-data.csv" and a location of s3://dgt-raw//accounts/account1/ ?

Is the crawler working correctly, and the capabilities of the crawler been different to my expectations, or is there something I havn't done correctly?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it seems like its still a buggy (as per the lynda.com Storage & Data Mangement video). I put another csv file into the dgt-raw/accounts/account1 - and volia! It seems to pick both tables up, with correct locations and names. Random.